# Генерация списка доступных фильтров

Tags: php, laravel

Проект - интернет магазин на laravel(5.3).
Задача касается 2х страниц. Категории товаров (страница с товарами выбранной категории) и страница с результатами поиска.
Нужно чтобы на странице выводились только те фильтры, которые доступны для данного списка товаров.
Количество видов фильтров что-то около 10.

К примеру, если открыта категория "Корм для животных", в нем не должны вылезать условные фильтры "Размер\обхват талии" или "Тип космет средства".

Как правильно реализовать генерацию списка необходимых фильтров? (если возможно - с примером).

Если с категориями товаров есть идеи(хоть и костыльные), то со страницей результата поиска не могу придумать адекватное решение.

P.S. часть характеристик товаров (под фильтры) хранится в основной таблице товаров, часть ссылается на другие таблицы.

Comment: Ну наверное нужно определять, какие атрибуты к какому типу товаров относятся. Тяжело будет привести хоть какой-то наглядный пример, так как очевидно что в разных проектах разные реализации.

Comment: Это "всё просто" - фильтр формируешь из атрибутов выбранных товаров (в данном случае критерий отбора - категория). Единственная сложность - сделать это с минимальной нагрузкой. Но это тоже решаемо.